# Google Analytics tracking across multiple domains - not showing domain, not tracking

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I have been trying to get Google Analytics (Universal) working across two related domains, say www.foo.com and app.foo.com.

According to the Google Docs, I should be able to use the Universal code with domain 'auto' and it should just work.

I did the standard tracking codes in both sites (ID changed):

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'MY-CODE-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

I have two problems:

1. When I go to "Real-Time" pane, I see the visitor count and page visited correct when I go to a page in the www site, but nothing for the app. site.
2. I cannot get it to show me the domain name of the page visited. I tried using custom filters on the global view per https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en#Next but it makes no difference.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check with analytics debugger, wasp or a cookie manager that in your subdomain analytics is actually working?

Comment: As I show my ignorance and say, "if they were server-side code or my own JS, I would know how to, but I don't know how to debug if analytics is working." My basic guess would be to check if requests of some kind to Google, but....

Comment: OK, good point. Fired up in Firefox (pun intended). www site is showing, after loading the analytics.js, that it is doing a GET for http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?<lots of params> The same does not happen on app.

Comment: That means there's some problem in the implementation. Look at the differences between analytics in www and in app. Even in where are positioned on the page (but they should be both before the closing <head> tag).

Comment: Anyway, install Google Analytics Debugger on your browser, activate it and then open up the console. You'll see clearly if it's working or not.

Comment: GA Debugger? Cool extension for Chrome, never saw it. Nice!

Comment: @lucgenti right you are. Please put that up as an answer and I will accept it. Once I did it, I saw that the app had a condition for the tracking code (avoid localhost because of dev) that was backwards.

Comment: Also, maybe, in this case, PEBKAC? :-)

Comment: It could happen and it's very frequent. :) Happy you solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `analytics.js`, there's no need to do more.

So, first thing to check is the implementation of the code.

One good way is to use the official Google Analytics Debugger for Chrome
https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gaTrackingTroubleshooting#usingDebugger
Then activate it, open up the console with F12 and see if the code is working, like this:

[image: Google Analytics Debugger for Chrome example]

If `Initializing Google Analytics` isn't present, here's the problem. So, look back to both the script and see what could be the differences between the working one and the other.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. The `send` was not getting sent.